# Get firebase snapshot value outside of function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to send some generated data to the to a specific object child.

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var key = user.uid;

// Set path for created user to be UID
var createProfileRef = firebase.database().ref("profiles/" + key);
var info;
createProfileRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var getData = snapshot.val();
  info = Object.keys(getData)[0];
});

// Save Plan to logged inn user
var sendData = firebase.database().ref("profiles/" + key + "/" + info + sendDate);

savePlan(sendFat, sendProtein, sendCarbohydrate);
function savePlan(sendFat, sendProtein, sendCarbohydrate) {
  var addData = sendData.push();
    addData.set({
    Macros_Fat: sendFat,
    Macros_Protein: sendProtein,
    Macros_Carbohydrate: sendCarbohydrate,
});
```

The only thing I need for this to work is to get the value of the variable **"info"**.  I just can't get it to get transferred outside of the function it is declared in...

If I place the function **savePlan** inside the snapshot it works, but it generated around 1000 keys constantly until I exit the application.

Comment: sendDate at the end of sendData path is just a var containing the current date

Comment: on() is asynchronous.  It doesn't wait for the callback to happen before continuing.  Also, you probably want to be using once() so that the callback only triggers a single time.  Put your code that requires the snapshot inside the callback, or call another function in your callback that gets passed the data.

Comment: Amazing! That makes a lot of sense as well. Thanks for the help Doug.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do that is by setting the variable value in localStorage in the firebase function itself and get it outside the function from localStorage.

Here's the code:

```js
// in firebase function
localStorage.setItem('info',info)

//outside the firebase function

localStorage.getItem('info');
```